# Should I use try-with-resource in flatMap for an I/O-based stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

A `Stream` is an `AutoCloseable` and if I/O-based, should be used in a `try-with-resource` block. What about intermediate I/O-based streams which are inserted via `flatMap()`? Example:

```
try (var foos = foos()) {
   return foos.flatMap(Foo::bars).toArray(Bar[]::new);
}
```

vs.

```
try (var foos = foos()) {
  return foos.flatMap(foo -> {
    try (var bars = foo.bars()) {
      return bars;
    }
  }).toArray(Bar[]::new);
}
```

The `flatMap()` documentation says:

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.

Well, that's the happy path. What if there happened an exception in between? Would that stream then stay unclosed and potentially leaking resources? Should I then always use a `try-with-resource` also for intermediate streams?

Comment: "should always be in a try-with-resource block" –> "*may* be used in a try-with-resources block"

Comment: You don't need to put your stream in a try-with-resource block if it doesn't consume any underlying resources.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. The try-with-resource question makes only sense with IO-based streams. Let's consider these streams only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no sense in a construct like

```
return foos.flatMap(foo -> {
    try (var bars = foo.bars()) {
        return bars;
    }
}).toArray(Bar[]::new);
```

as that would close the stream *before* it is returned to the caller, which makes the sub-stream entirely unusable.

In fact, it is impossible for the function’s code to ensure that the closing will happen at the appropriate place, which is outside the function. That’s surely the reason why the API designers decided that you don’t have to, and the Stream implementation will take care.

This also applies to the exceptional case. The Stream still ensures that the stream gets closed, once the function has returned it to the Stream:

```
try {
    IntStream.range(1, 3)
        .flatMap(i -> {
            System.out.println("creating "+i);
            return IntStream.range('a', 'a'+i)
                    .peek(j -> {
                        System.out.println("processing sub "+i+" - "+(char)j);
                        if(j=='b') throw new IllegalStateException();
                    })
                    .onClose(() -> System.out.println("closing "+i));
        })
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println("consuming "+(char)i));
} catch(IllegalStateException ex) {
    System.out.println("caught "+ex);
}
```

```
creating 1
processing sub 1 - a
consuming a
closing 1
creating 2
processing sub 2 - a
consuming a
processing sub 2 - b
closing 2
caught java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

You may play with the conditions, to see that a constructed Stream is always closed. For elements of the outer Stream which do not get processed, there will be no Stream at all.

For a Stream operation like `.flatMap(Foo::bars)` or `.flatMap(foo -> foo.bars())`, you can assume that once `bars()` successfully created and returned a Stream, it will be passed to the caller for sure and properly closed.

A different scenario would be mapping functions which perform operations after the Stream creation which could fail, e.g.

```
.flatMap(foo -> {
    Stream<Type> s = foo.bar();
    anotherOperation(); // Stream is not closed if this throws
    return s;
})
```

In this case, it would be necessary to ensure the closing in the exceptional case, but only in the exceptional case:

```
.flatMap(foo -> {
    Stream<Type> s = foo.bar();
    try {
        anotherOperation();
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        try(s) { throw t; } // close and do addSuppressed if follow-up error
    }
    return s;
})
```

but obviously, you should follow the general rule to keep lambdas simple, in which case you don’t need such protection.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It isn't even possible to put the intermediate stream into a `try-with-resource`. Thanks for providing a real world example. I guess it's then the API documentation of `flatMap()` which caused the confusion about the unhappy trail.

Answer (score 2):

In Stream or not, you have to close the IO resources at the relevant place.
The `flatMap()` method is a general stream method and so it not aware of IO resources you opened inside it.
But Why `flatMap()` would behave differently from any method that manipulates IO resources ? 
For example if you manipulate IO in `map()`, you could get the same issue (no releasing resource) if an exception occurs.
Closing a stream (as in `flatMap()`) will not make it release all resources opened in the stream operation.
Some methods do that, `File.lines(Path)` for example.  But if you open yourself some resources in `flatMap()`, the closing of these resources will not do automatically when the stream is closed.
For example here the flatMap processing doesn't close the `FileInputStream`s opened :

```
 ...
 .stream()
 .flatMap(foo -> {
    try {
       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("..."));                                  
       //...
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
         // handle
     }

 })
```

You have to close it explicitly :

```
 ...
 .stream()
 .flatMap(foo -> {
     try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("...")){
         //...
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // handle
     }
    // return
 })
```

So yes if the statements used inside the `flatMap()` or any method manipulates some IO resources, you want to close them in any case by surrounding it with a `try-with-resources` statement to make them free.

Comment: @Markus Malkusch Sure. Agreed in this case. I updated.

Comment: Doesn't that make the Stream API a bit half assed? I referenced that part from the doc where it states that flatMap() would close the intermediate stream. However what is that worth if that happens only for the happy path? Also flatMap() is different in that it works on `AutoClosable` which can be closed, `map()` doesn't. Also there is `Stream.concat`which does a `stream.onClose(Streams.composedClose(a, b))`. I was hopeing that will happen here as well.

Comment: IHMO, you give too much importance to this `flatMap()` specificity that it should have. The fact that `flatMap()` closes the underlying streams is an information provided by the API. So yes you can rely on since that is API information. Personally I think that the stream is closed to makes things clearer : why keeping open an intermediary stream that was consumed by the enclosing stream ? (1/2)

Comment: But as shown in my example, that specificity is not enough to ensure that all opened resources be correctly closed : happy scenario or exception scenario. Look at `Files.walk()`, `Files.lines()` that return `Stream<Path>` and  `Stream<String>`, it gives similar advises about the requirement to close the resources. (2/2)

Comment: I understood the question as discussing the `Stream` returned by the function, which surely is not a `FileInputStream`. And closing a `Stream` before returning, would break the entire operation.