# How to consume more than one Stream with the "same" Collector, without concatenating them?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Imagine we have a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html), and we want to feed it the contents of a succession of [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)s.

The most natural way of doing it would be [concatenating](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)) the `Stream`s and feeding the `Collector` with the concatenation. But this might not be optimal: for example, if each `Stream` reads from a scarce resource allocated with a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), it would be expensive to have all `Stream`s at once.

Also, sometimes we might not even have direct access to the `Stream`s, we might only have an opaque method that "feeds" a `Collector` that it receives as parameter, and returns the result.

How to feed a `Collector` from multiple sources in those cases?

Comment: Just use `flatMap`; the streams will not exist at the same time and the documentation even specifies that `close` will be invoked after all elements have been processed.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54829307/2711488) for a discussion of `flatMap` vs try-with-resources.

Comment: @Holger That answer says that putting try-with-resources inside the `flatMap` callback is problematic. And pulling all the try-with-resources "outside" would be wasteful. So my question still stands.

Comment: For a concrete situation, imagine that we want to consume with a `Collector`  the lines of every file inside a 10000-file folder, using `File.lines()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072035/why-is-files-lines-and-similar-streams-not-automatically-closed without having at any point more than a single file descriptor open, and also ensuring proper cleanup in the face of any I/O exception that may crop up while reading.

Comment: You objections simply don’t make any sense. You should read answers to the end, not just the first few lines. Again, **flatMap closes the stream**, try-with-resources is just about closing the resource which is not necessary with flatMap, because **flatMap closes the stream**. It’s not even clear what “pulling all the try-with-resources outside” is supposed to mean. You can not use try-with-resources with flatMap. Point. And you don’t need to use try-with-resources with flatMap, because **flatMap closes the stream**. Point.

Comment: @Holger It does seem like `flatMap` closes sub-streams even in the event of an exception. I feel that the official documentation is a bit ambiguous in that respect. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function) It says "Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream." but it wasn't clear—at least to me—if that also covered exceptional termination, in addition of normal sub-stream exhaustion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [concatenating](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)) `Stream`s that have been previously allocated with a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), a possible solution is to splice them in a "top-level" `Stream` using [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)), and then consume the resulting `Stream` with the `Collector`.

The [usual recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073306/1364288) for safe resource handling with `Stream`s is to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). However, `flatMap` behaves specially in that respect: it itself ensures that the spliced sub-`Stream`s are closed, *both* when they are "exhausted" in the main `Stream`, and when the `Stream` is interrupted because of an exception.

To my mind, the wording in the [`flatMap` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) feels a bit ambiguous about cleanup in the face of exceptions:

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.

But this experiments show that sub-`Stream`s are closed even when an exception crops up:

```
// This prints "closed!" before the stack trace
Stream.of(1,2,3)
.flatMap((i) ->
     Stream.<String>generate(() -> { throw new RuntimeException(); })
     .limit(2)
     .onClose(() -> System.err.println("closed!"))
).forEach(System.err::println);
```

Comment: "Closing Java Streams with AutoCloseable" https://mikemybytes.com/2021/01/26/closing-java-streams-with-autocloseable/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use this auxiliary `duplicate` function:

```
static <T,A,R> Collector<T,A,Collector<T,A,R>> duplicate(Collector<T,A,R> collector) {
    final Supplier<A> supplier = collector.supplier();
    final BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator = collector.accumulator();
    final BinaryOperator<A> combiner = collector.combiner();
    final Function<A, R> finisher = collector.finisher();
    final Function<A, Collector<T,A,R>> newFinisher = (finalState) ->
            Collector.of(() -> finalState, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
    return Collector.of(supplier,accumulator,combiner,newFinisher);
}
```

`duplicate` takes a `Collector` and returns a `Collector` just like the first one, except that instead of the original result type, it returns *another* `Collector` as result, one that we can later pass to further `Stream`s:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    final Collector<Integer, ?, Integer> summy0 =
         Collectors.summingInt(i -> i);

    final Collector<Integer, ?, Integer> summy1 =
         Stream.<Integer>of(1, 2, 3).collect(duplicate(summy0));

    final Collector<Integer, ?, Integer> summy2 =
         Stream.<Integer>of(4, 5, 6).collect(duplicate(summy1));

    System.out.println(Stream.<Integer>of().collect(summy2));
}
```

Comment: The contract of a collector’s supplier is to return a new empty container on each evaluation. Always returning the same instance, not to speak of a non-empty result of a previous operation, violates the contract. So it doesn’t come as surprise that adding `.parallel()` to the second stream will produces invalid results.

Comment: @Holger You're right, it appears that my solution breaks the contract.